# Bluetoothlescanner stop scanning or scan less often when screen is turned off

Tags: java, android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy, foreground-service

I created simple foreground service for scanning BLE devices. It should scan for devices all the time. I created my own BLE devices which transmit one frame per 0,5s. I have two debug devices one with Android 9 and second with Android 6.

First of all I noticed that I doesn't get all BLE frames. I should get about 20 frames every 10 seconds but:

- Device with Android 9 gets about 6-7 frames,
- Device with Android 6 gets about 15-17 frames, but device scan at certain intervals (scans for 10 seconds and then stops for 5-7 seconds).

Secondly I noticed that when device screen is turned off it scan even worse (or stop scan at all):

- Device with Android 9 stops scanning for BLE devices 1 minute after screen is turnded off,
- Device with Android 6 after turning screen off gets about 6 frames.

Service code :

```
public class DeviceScan extends Service {

    BluetoothLeScanner btScanner;
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";
    List<ScanFilter> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
    {
        filterList.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName("MYBEACON").build());
    }

    private ScanCallback leScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                Log.e("Adress: ",result.getDevice().getAddress());
                Log.e("RSSI: ", " rssi: " + result.getRssi());
        }
    };

    public void startScanning(){
        btScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.startScan(filterList, new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .setReportDelay(0) //when I use different value than 0, stop scanning
                        .build(),leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    public void stopScanning() {
        btScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                btScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AlbumActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
                .setContentText("Scanning")
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);


        startScanning();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Foreground Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which phones are you using? There are several factors at play here, but for starters, the BLE results per device manufacturer (and phone) are wildly different (but they're slowly converging to similar qualities). Additionally, you'd have to check what the LOW_LATENCY scan timings are, and try to figure out the probability of those scan timings overlapping with your advertising intervals. iOS's advertising recommendations are a great example of how to maximize discovery probability https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9834

Comment: Regarding the device screen off, is the foreground service being killed when the screen turns off?

Comment: @SJoshi Devices: Xiaomi mi 6 (Android  9),Samsung Galaxy Tab S SM-T700 (Android 6). 
According to android.developers about LOW_LATENCY `"Scan using highest duty cycle. It's recommended to only use this mode when the application is running in the foreground."` Can't find specific scan timings but Samsung gets almoust all frames so it should't be a problem.
I think that service isn't killed because when I turn on screen, devices behave like before screen was turn off.

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow code it's work for me.
You need to **add empty ScanFilter** and set **ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                ScanFilter.Builder builder = new ScanFilter.Builder();
                builder.setManufacturerData(0x004c, new byte[]{});// apply iBeacon Filter
                filters.add(builder.build());
            }

            ScanSettings.Builder scanSettingBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
            scanSettingBuilder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);
```

Comment: But I need to use ScanFilter what's then ?